# Abrir link externo dentro da pagina principal da webview

Tags: android, webview

Eu tenho uma aplicativo carregado na 100% na `WebView`, eu coloquei o link onde tem a aplicação e todo o aplicativo é via web em php.

Só que tem links que não fazem parte da pagina que são links externos (exemplo `www.google.com.br`) e gostaria que ele abrisse no próprio navegador e nao dentro da `WebView`

Minha tentativa:

`<a href="https://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">  busca  </a>`

Mas abre dentro da própria `WebView`, eu gostaria que só os links das paginas web da aplicação carregassem dentro da `WebView e links externos fossem carregados fora.

Essa possibilidade é possível? Onde tenho que alterar para obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa implementar o **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**

exemplo:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains("http://www.seuendereco.com")) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            } else {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(intent);
               return true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Esse código irá fazer com que todos os links abram dentro da webView.

Comment: oi leonardo, obrigada por tua atençao ao meu problema..então.. isso ja acontece.. eu quero que apenas os links que nao façam parte da pagina abram fora da webview.. pq o google por exemplo esta carregando dentro .. eu quero que só so arquivos do site principal da webview carregue ali .. links que nao fazem parte como o google por exemplo abra fora do navegador da webview..

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, você precisa colocar um IF, se a url requisitada tiver um pedaço da url do seu site, abre dentro do webview, caso contrário, abre fora.

Comment: Valeuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu leonardo Tks por tua ajuda!!!